# Physical location of the processes assigned by the MPI run-time system

Tags: mpi

When we launch an MPI program with the command say `mpirun -np 4 a.out` on a cluster, then 
how does the MPI run-time system assign the processes across the CPU's?

What I mean is, suppose it finds an idle quad-core CPU in the cluster , will it run all the 4 processes on that CPU, or will it find 4 CPU's and run 4 processes with 1 process per CPU?

Does this depend on the particular implementation of MPI?

And should I be bothered by the particular configuration which MPI would pick for me (4 processes on one CPU or 1 process per CPU on 4 CPU's)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it depends on the MPI implementation, and yes it matters.   For instance, if you were expecting to be able to use a nodes worth of memory per MPI task, and you find yourself loading 4 tasks on a single node and nothing on the others, you're going to run into serious problems.   Similarly, if you are running on 4 8-core nodes, and you were running 4 mpi tasks with 8 OpenMP threads each, there's a big difference between using 1 task and 8 threads for each of the 4 nodes, or 4 tasks and 32 threads on one node and nothing on the others.

The most common MPI implementations out there on x86-type hardware are OpenMPI or MPICH2-based.  OpenMPI will fill up a node before going to the next one; you can change that behavior with, for instance, giving it the "--bynode" option, where it will assign one task to one node, the next task to the next, etc, and wrapping around to the first node again as needed.  (OpenMPI also has --bysocket and --bycore for finer control, and the very useful --display-map option which shows you exactly what's going where).

With mpich2-based MPIs, you can give it the -rr option for "round robin", which will round robin between nodes (eg, OpenMPI's --bynode behaviour).

In either case, on linux-type systems you can always run *eg* 'mpirun -np 4 hostname' as a quick and dirty way to find out which hosts your mpirun command would launch processes on.